# How do i only pull the top "x" rows from a table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query

```
$query_return = database::query("SELECT * FROM tw ORDER BY time DESC");
```

that pulls all the rows, however I only want the top x=8 rows.

How do I modify it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use LIMIT:

```
SELECT * FROM tw ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 8
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a limit clause:

```
$query_return = database::query("SELECT * FROM tw ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 8");
```

Answer (score 0):

If code is for MS-SQL use TOP 
e.g.
SELECT TOP (8) * FROM ....

Comment: Care to comment your code, what does it adds to the accepted answer? Check this [metaSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) and [Jon Skeet: Coding Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx) on how to give a correct answer.